# radiation of rotating spherical shell with constant or changing angular speed

Tags: electromagnetism

Does a rotating spherical shell with uniform charge density radiate for both cases of constant and changing angular speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating spherical shell possesses magnetic dipole moment $\vec{m}={Q \vec{\omega} R^2}/{3}$. Rotation with a constant angular speed does not cause changes in the electromagnetic field of this system, so there would be no radiation.

On the other hand, if the angular speed changes, then there would be [magnetic dipole radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_radiation#Magnetic_dipole_radiation) with radiated power proportional to $|\ddot{m}|^2$.