# Radiation of rotating spherical shell with constant angular speed

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

I know this has been asked twice here but none of the explanations made me realize why it is zero. One of the answers says dipole moment for constant angular velocity is also a constant vector and therefore the electric field is constant but I don't see how that could mean that something in the Poynting vector makes it somehow null.
A book I was reading mentions that the current density must be constant since $\rho$ is constant but I'm not getting how to derive an expression for $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ or $\mathbf{E}$ that depends on the derivative of $\mathbf{J}$ to get a zero.
From classical theoretical physics by Greiner we get this explanation

[image: ..]

But I would need to derive this expression to use it

[image: Page 436 of the same book]

However form [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/392824/radiation-of-rotating-spherical-shell-with-constant-or-changing-angular-speed) previous thread the answer seem to be more intuitive but I do not get how it'd mean there is no radiation

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is?  What result are you seeking clarification on?

Comment: It'd be why the radiation for a sphericall uniformly charged sphere with constant angular momentum should be zero?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct.  The first thing that comes to mind is Synchrotron radiation https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_34.html#Ch34-S3

Comment: I have read a little on that approach but from my understanding sychroton radiation implies there is a radiation in this case and also considers the relativistic effects which was avoided during my course because the teacher wanted the course to be entirely classical, I'm goinf to take a closer look just in case